# Converting $y'' + 2y' + (\lambda + 1)y = 0$ to Sturm-Liouville form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I am trying to convert the DE

$$y'' + 2y' + (\lambda + 1)y = 0$$

to Sturm-Liouville form.

I know that Sturm-Liouville form is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\left( p(x) \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{x}} \right) + (q(x) + \lambda r(x)) \phi = 0$$

So it seems that we have $q(x) = 1 = r(x)$, but how do I find the $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\left( p(x) \dfrac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{x}} \right)$ part?

This actually seems similar to the process of finding an integrating factor, except that, in this case, we have a second-order ODE.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory#The_integrating_factor_for_a_general_second-order_differential_equation
There is indeed an "integrating factor" that's used. There's how to put any second order ODE into SL form.

Comment: You want $(p y')' = py'' + p'y' = y'' + 2y'$ so how about multiplying through your original DE by $e^{2x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comment, given
$$y'' + 2y' + (\lambda + 1)y = 0$$
You can multiply by the "integrating factor" $\mu(x) = e^{\int 2 dx} = e^{2x}$,
$$e^{2x}y'' + 2e^{2x}y' + (\lambda + 1)e^{2x}y = 0$$
At which point you have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{2x} y' \right) + (e^{2x} + \lambda e^{2x})y = 0 $$
as desired.